# What commands can be given in the Kindle's search box?

Tags: kindle, amazon, time-to-read, software

In [this forum thread](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle/ref=cm_cd_pg_pg1?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdPage=1&cdThread=TxPPS6DELQ2IBY), a user explains that the Kindle's reading speed algorithm can be reset by typing ";ReadingTimeReset" in the Kindle's search box. The user states he was told by a member of Amazon's support team.
It seems obvious that this is a hidden mechanism for passing commands to the Kindle's software. What other commands can be given this way?

Comment: For reference: these commands, at least on the kindle DX, need to be run on the search box on the list of books. The search box inside a book does not seem to work

Answer (score 21):

At least the following are supposed to work, although I haven't verified them:

```
;debugOn // verbose logging
;debugOff // non-verbose logging
~help
~usbNetwork  // starts a Dropbear SSH server
;ReadingTimeOff - switches off the reading time display
;ReadingTimeOn - switches on the reading time display
;ReadingTimeReset - resets the reading time computation
@author AuthorName keyword
@store keyword
@web keyword
@wiki keyword
@time
```

As @Tim pointed out in the comments, `~usbNetwork` is non-standard, and some of the other "searches" on here may be hacks that require installation of additional software.

The following may be Touch-only; I can't verify this:

```
;dm - Dump messages to /documents
;dh - Dump cvm heap
;dt - Dump cvm stack
;shpm - set device to shipping mode
;urst - Reset user partition, deletes content of hidden System folder, Audible folder, Documents and tts folder. 
        Before using do a complete backup of your device
;debugPaint - log painting functions
;debugPref - pref level logging
;dP - alias of ;debugPref
;311 - change carrier settings
;411 - server information
;611 - wan information
;711 - wifi information
;fc-cache - updates fontconfig's cache, then restart the framework
;setTime - sets kindle time to unix clock
;st - alias of ;setTime (format: yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM – e.g.: ;st 2012-07-22 17:59)
~ds - Never show screen saver   (then you cannot lock the kindle till next reboot. 
                                 Rebooting the Kindle will restore the screen saver 
                                 lock and, hopefully, everything goes fine!)
```

The following are apparently Paperwhite-only, but I can't verify this:

```
";dm" : "/usr/bin/dm.sh",
";dmcc" : "/usr/local/bin/dmcc.sh",
";dh" : "/usr/bin/dh.sh",
";dt" : "/usr/bin/dt.sh",
";wifipopup" : "/usr/local/bin/wifipopup.sh",
";sandbox" : "/usr/local/bin/sandbox.sh",
";sbx" : "/usr/local/bin/sandbox.sh",
";shpm" : "/usr/sbin/shipping_mode",
";lzzl" : "/usr/sbin/shipping_mode",
";urst" : "/usr/sbin/userstore_reset",
";usbnetwork" : "/usr/local/bin/usbnetwork.sh",
";un" : "/usr/local/bin/usbnetwork.sh",
";di" : "/usr/local/bin/indexerdisable.sh",
"`stopIndexing" : "/usr/local/bin/indexerstop.sh",
"`startIndexing" : "/usr/local/bin/indexerenable.sh",
"`disableIndexing" : "/usr/local/bin/indexerdisable.sh",
"`indexStatus" : "/usr/local/bin/indexstatus.sh",
";ddc" : "/usr/local/bin/dynconfig.sh",
";resetConfig" : "/usr/local/bin/resetConfig.sh",
";rc" : "/usr/local/bin/resetConfig.sh",
";twoFingerChromeOn" : "/usr/local/bin/altChrome.sh 1",
";homeKeyChromeOn" : "/usr/local/bin/altChrome.sh 2",
";normalChrome" : "/usr/local/bin/altChrome 0",
";debugOn" : "/usr/bin/debugOn.sh",
";debugPaint" : "/usr/bin/debugPaint.sh",
";debugOff" : "/usr/bin/debugOff.sh",
";debugPerf" : "/usr/bin/debugPerf.sh",
";dP" : "/usr/bin/debugPerf.sh",
";311" : "/usr/bin/311.sh",
";411" : "/usr/bin/411.sh",
";611" : "/usr/bin/611.sh",
";711" : "/usr/bin/711.sh",
";setTime" : "/usr/bin/dateTime.sh",
";st" : "/usr/bin/dateTime.sh",
"~ds" : "/usr/bin/ds.sh",
";toggleLight" : "/usr/bin/light.sh",
";fc-cache" : "/usr/bin/fc-cache.sh",
";htmlViewer" : "/usr/local/bin/htmlViewer.sh",
";installHtml" : "/usr/local/bin/installHtmlViewer.sh",
";merchant" : "/usr/local/bin/merchant.sh",
";updateCamp" : "/usr/bin/updateCamp.sh"
```

[Source](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_Touch_Hacking#Search_Bar_Shortcuts)

Here is [an interesting tutorial on how to root your Kindle](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/kindle-root) (not directly relevant to the question, in that it's not just a list of search commands, but relevant to Kindle hacking generally).

Comment: Note that this list probably contains all commands that are possible on an unrooted Kindle, but some of them are non standard. At least usbNetwork is a hack, that must be installed separately and I would assume the same for all commands that start a script in /usr/local/bin

Comment: @Tim I thought `~usbNetwork` was a legitimate debug feature at least on some Kindle 4 models?

Answer (score 3):

The commands `~ds` and `;411` worked for my kindle paperwhite 3. The `;411` command even measures the temperature of the display! To re-enable screensaver for `~ds` command, you must reboot the kindle paperwhite a few times. Mine took two times.

Answer (score 2):

";dm" gets you the device logs, checked on kindle paperwhite 1, very useful

Answer (score 0):

`;dm` worked for Kindle 10th Gen

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this [comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kindle/comments/5nb284/anyway_to_disable_screensaver_for_paperwhite_2015/dcaxz2a?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) that states that `~disableScreensaver` and `~resumeScreensaver` could work, but it didn't for me. It might be for older Kindles only. I have a Kindle Paperwhite 10th gen.